# Poor gradient perfomance in Firefox

Tags: performance, firefox, css, gradient

I'm currently working on a css3 gradient background which works fine on Chrome but terrible on Firefox. I noticed it's due the `background-size` property in my css. Is there any way to make exactly the same background but with different methods?

```css
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cccccc 0%, #cccccc 25%, #bbbbbb 25%, #bbbbbb 50%, #cccccc 50%, #cccccc 75%, #bbbbbb 75%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cccccc 0%, #cccccc 25%, #bbbbbb 25%, #bbbbbb 50%, #cccccc 50%, #cccccc 75%, #bbbbbb 75%);
    background-size: 30px 30px:
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a known bug in Firefox: see [bug 657603](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=657603) for more.

Comment: yep!, looks like it thanks.. i got it fixed by using a png with the pattern instead of css gradients (i didnt want to use img), so i'll recommend no to use ccs gradient for now

Comment: @aXul If you don't need help with your question, then add an answer and close it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bug657603](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=657603)

turns out it is a bug on mozilla firefox... poor performance when using low res gradient patterns on backgrounds, as  Jonah Bishop posted